# Bootstrap popup modal with Get php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

please help me.. i am having a trouble with the popup modal.. how to get a certain data/value and display it to the modal.. I dynamically fetch a data from database and display it to html form, when i clicked one of the displayed item the modal popup should show containing the said description. My problem is that when I clicked one of the items it popup the modal but it contains all the data that is not related to the item that i Clicked.

Example i fetched form database this 2 items below (see pictures below),[image]
 when i clicked one of them the popup modal should show containing the said value like below [image]
but i am having a trouble when i clicked one of them it show all the description with the other item like below
[image]
my code is here

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#btnShow").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url: 'prologue.php?story=$row[title]',
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
      },
      error:function(xhr,code,text){
        alert("error occoured : "+text);
      }
    });
$('#demoModal').modal('show');
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Compiled Story</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../js/js/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../logo.png">


</head>
<body>

<table class="story-albums-lib" style="margin-left: 250px;">

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scenezone");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM create_story
WHERE title IN (SELECT story FROM story_chapter WHERE status = '1');";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Fetch all
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if ($i % 5 == 0) {
echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td><a href='prologue.php?story=$row[title]'><img src='../stories/" .$row['image']."' alt='Image' id='btnShow' style='width: 200px; height: 250px;  border-radius: 8px;'></a>

<br><p id='btnShow' style='margin-left:50px;'>".$row["title"]."</p>

</td>";
if ($i % 5 == 4) {
echo "</tr>";
}
$i++;
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $row ['email'];?></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" id="btnchapterlist" class="btn btn-primary">Start Reading</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my prologue.php

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "scenezone";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM create_story
WHERE title IN (SELECT story FROM story_chapter WHERE status = '1');";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<center>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><img src='../stories/".$row['image']."' alt='Image' class='img-responsive;' style='width: 200px; height: 250px;'>
        <br><p> Title: ".$row["title"]."
        <br>Genre : ".$row["genre"]."
        <br>Author : ".$row["pen_name"]."
         <br>Prologue : ".$row["description"]."</p>
      
        </td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</center>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You must put everything which is related to your modal window into the success function of your ajax request.

Comment: like the ur request??

Answer (score 0):

Did you have tried to use a `foreach()` or a `for()` loop to populate your modal?
Consider also to use an `$.each()` inside the success function of your ajax request.

EDIT: As requested here is how i will try to fetch the needed data, I will not include the [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), this is not a problem during the develop of your page, but you need to implement them in the release version for security reason.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scenezone");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM create_story
WHERE title IN (SELECT story FROM story_chapter WHERE status = '1');";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Fetch all
foreach($result as $row):
$title = $row[title];    
$email = $row['email'];
$image = $row['image'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Compiled Story</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../js/js/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../logo.png">


</head>
<body>

<table class="story-albums-lib" style="margin-left: 250px;">
</div>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $email; ?></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<tr>
<td><a href='prologue.php?story=<? echo $title; ?>'>
<img src='../stories/" .<? echo $image; ?>."' alt='Image' id='btnShow' style='width: 200px; height: 250px;  border-radius: 8px;'></a>
<br><p id='btnShow' style='margin-left:50px;'>".<? echo $title ?>."</p>    
</td>
</tr>
<? endforeach;
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" id="btnchapterlist" class="btn btn-primary">Start Reading</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes,I think that in your case it will be helpful. If you want to use ajax, the best solution to display all items is the `$,each()` loop in the success function of your request.

Comment: can you provide a source related with this?? I'm having a trouble with this.. I already tried using that but it's no use.. i still got the same problem

Comment: @Rose I've quickly tried to give you a sample of the code, but I haven't tested it, I suppose that it will be work. Take a look at the edit of my answer.